# error in mgcv "incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm running a fairly hefty gam im mgcv (R version 4.3.1 on linux, ubuntu 22.0), and i've been running across this error. here is what the gam looks like:

```
model_ndvi <-
   gam(list(
      # mean predictor
         NDVI ~ cutblock +
            s(long, lat, bs = 'ds', k = 100, by = cutblock) + #observe trends geographically
            s(year, bs = 'cr', k = 7, by = cutblock) + #view trends over time
            s(doy, bs = 'cc', k = 8, by = cutblock) + #view yearly trends
            s(cb_age, bs = "cr", k = 3) + #view trends by cutblock age
            ti(year, doy, bs = 'cc') + #view how yearly trends changed over time
            ti(cb_age, year, bs = 'cr'), #see how the cutblock trends changed over time
        # variance predictor
          ~ cutblock +
            s(long, lat, bs = 'ds', k = 50, by = cutblock) +
            s(year, bs = 'cr', k = 5, by = cutblock) +
            s(doy, bs = 'cc', k = 4, by = cutblock)+
            s(cb_age, bs = "cr", k = 3) +
            ti(year, doy, bs = 'cc') +
            ti(cb_age, year, bs = 'cr')),
        family = betals(), #beta location scale distribution for the data
        data = babyd,
        method = 'REML',
        knots = list(doy = c(0.5, 366.5)),
        control = gam.control(nthreads = 30), trace = TRUE)
```

i've been running across the error
`Error in backsolve(L, forwardsolve(t(L), (D * A)[piv, ]))[ipiv, , drop = FALSE] :  incorrect number of dimensions`
when trying to run the model. given that my dataset is about 87 GB large, i have been testing the model on a much smaller subset of data (about 90 MB), obtained from the original dataset using the `slice` function. from what i have seen, this error has to do with subsetting data that doesn't exist. i was worried that when i extracted a smaller amount of data from the original data set, there wouldn't be enough unique values and that would cause this error, but after inspecting the data by running `unique` on each variable i have seen that, as far as i know, there are more than enough unique values in each variable for the model to run.

here is a snippet of what the data looks like (using `head`):

```
  long      lat        NDVI    cutblock harvestyr  date    dec_date year doy cb_age
1 -127.2368 51.60493 -0.0275    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
2 -127.2368 51.60712 -0.0053    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
3 -127.2368 51.60932  0.1173    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
4 -127.2368 51.61151  0.2855    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
5 -127.2368 51.61371  0.2417    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
6 -127.2368 51.61591  0.4240    FALSE        NA 2000-02-18 2000.131 2000  49     NA
```

and here is what it looks like when i run `str` on the data:

```
'data.frame':   1474926 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ long     : num  -127 -127 -127 -127 -127 ...
 $ lat      : num  51.6 54 53.4 52.9 52.1 ...
 $ NDVI     : num  -0.0275 0.4184 -0.0103 -0.0292 0.5711 ...
 $ cutblock : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ harvestyr: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ date     : Date, format: "2000-02-18" "2000-02-18" "2000-02-18" "2000-02-18" ...
 $ dec_date : num  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ year     : int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ doy      : int  49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 ...
 $ cb_age   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

for a bit more context about the model in case anyone needs more information - i'm looking at ndvi trends over the past 20 or so years within and outside of clearcut areas in forests (called cutblocks in the data) and trying to determine at what point these clearcut areas recover back to full productivity, taking into account the changes in both mean and variance. the `betals` function is a beta location scale distribution function, written for this project by simon wood (author of `mgcv`).

i've tried looking at the structure of the data to see if that is the issue, but all information online is very simple in relation to what i am trying to do. i'm wondering if anyone has come across this error before in mgcv! any help is appreciated :))

Comment: It’s not clear to me if the model works fine with the smaller subset or are you getting the same error? 1.4 million rows isn’t huge so I doubt this is some weird indexing limit. Things to check; `traceback()` after the error as `betals()` will be less well-tested than the other families so confirm if error is inside it or elsewhere. Try simplifying the model to isolate where the problem happens; set the variance to be a much simpler model say or even intercept only and try to fit with all the data & see if error persists.

Comment: I see you have `NA` in `cb_age`; long shot, but what if you select only the variables in the model and then use `complete.cases()` or whatever it’s called to get rid of `NA`s manually. It might be that tracking the missing values is going wrong somewhere with the multiple linear predictors. Having incorrect dimensions is often a sign that there’s a missing `drop =  FALSE` somewhere, which might point the finger at this new family, so debug and see where the error happens. Beyond that, you might need to go back to Simon on this one as we obviously can’t reproduce this without `betals`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you for your input! the error seems to be coming from the setup of the model (on the smaller data set, the full data set has yet to be tested). i replaced the NAs with 0s since the distinction is important to the analysis, but the error still seems to be occurring from the `cb_age` term. if you have any other ideas i am happy to hear them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to this ended up being quite simple: the location scale family wasn't automatically selecting the minimum possible number of knots for one of the terms. while i specified `k = 3`, the minimum was 5, so changing it fixed the error.

this seems to be an issue for other location scale distribution families in mgcv as well - we tested the model using `gaulss` and had the same error, but changing the knots fixed it.